# Solving PDE with a non-linear constraint in MATLAB

Tags: pde, matlab, numerical-modelling

I am trying to solve a DAE with a non-linear constraint. The governing equations have the following form.

[image]

The second equation is a constraint and it must be satisfied everywhere. Is there a way to use the ode solver in MATLAB to solve this type of system? If so, for example, ode15s, how could we couple the constraint into the mass matrix?

Comment: Yes, in your ODE solver in the RHS you will need to add a procedure solving the second equation, i.e., expressing $\Theta$ in terms of $c,t,x$.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to enforce this constraint by properly constructing the mass matrix, RHS, and Jacobian.  First, I will assume the index of the DAE is 1 and you have used the method of lines to take care of non-time derivatives in your problem.  Let's write the semidiscretized form as
$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{d \vec{c}}{dt} &= D \vec{f}(\vec{c}, t, \vec{x}, \vec{\theta}), \\
0 &= D \vec{\theta} + \vec{g}(\vec{c}, t, \vec{x}, \vec{\theta}),
\end{align*}
$$
where $D$ is a diffusion matrix and the $\vec{}$ notation indicates a vector representing values on grid points.

Note that MATLAB expects a problem of the form
$$
M y' = rhs(t, y),
$$
so let's requite the ODE as
$$
\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix} I & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}}_{\text{mass matrix}}
\begin{bmatrix} \vec{c} \\ \vec{\theta} \end{bmatrix}' =
\begin{bmatrix} D \vec{f}(\vec{c}, t, \vec{x}, \vec{\theta}) \\ D \vec{\theta} + \vec{g}(\vec{c}, t, \vec{x}, \vec{\theta}) \end{bmatrix}.
$$

Now all you need to do is write a function for this RHS and pass the mass matrix to the ODE solver (`ode15s`, `ode23t`, `ode23s`, etc) using `odeset`.

DAE solvers typically require a Jacobian, although MATLAB can approximate it if not provided.  If you do choose to provide the Jacobian, you would need to write a function to compute
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
D \frac{d\vec{f}}{d\vec{c}} & D \frac{d\vec{f}}{d\vec{\theta}} \\
\frac{d\vec{g}}{d\vec{c}} & D + \frac{d\vec{g}}{d\vec{\theta}}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: Thank you so much, Roberts. How do we check if the DAE has an index of 1? I have tried the same way as you described before but I kept getting the error "The DAE has an index greater than 1".